# Check if a predicate evaluates true for all elements in an iterable in Python

Tags: python

I am pretty sure there is a common idiom, but I couldn't find it with Google Search...

Here is what I want to do (in Java):

```java
// Applies the predicate to all elements of the iterable, and returns
// true if all evaluated to true, otherwise false
boolean allTrue = Iterables.all(someIterable, somePredicate);
```

How is this done "Pythonic" in Python?

Also would be great if I can get answer for this as well:

```java
// Returns true if any of the elements return true for the predicate
boolean anyTrue = Iterables.any(someIterable, somePredicate);
```

Answer (score 114, accepted):

Do you mean something like:

```
allTrue = all(somePredicate(elem) for elem in someIterable)
anyTrue = any(somePredicate(elem) for elem in someIterable)
```

Comment: These forms also have the advantage of "short-circuiting": `all` will terminate on the first `False` occurrence, and `any` will terminate on the first `True` occurrence.

Comment: Am I the only one who thinks this is unacceptably verbose for such a common operation?

Comment: Welcome to Python @cic. :D There is Coconut which is more amenable to FP http://coconut-lang.org/

Answer (score 18):

```
allTrue = all(map(predicate, iterable))
anyTrue = any(map(predicate, iterable))
```

Comment: To use short-circuiting here, you can replace `map` with `itertools.imap`.

Comment: @Space_C0wb0y - in Python 3, map returns an iterator, not a list, so imap would no longer be needed.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example that checks if a list contains all zeros:

```
x = [0, 0, 0]
all(map(lambda v: v==0, x))
# Evaluates to True

x = [0, 1, 0]
all(map(lambda v: v==0, x))
# Evaluates to False
```

Alternative you can also do:

```
all(v == 0 for v in x)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'all' and 'any' builtin functions in Python:

```
all(map(somePredicate, somIterable))
```

Here `somePredicate` is a function and `all` will check if bool() of that element is True.

Comment: If you're using Python 2, because you're chaining `map` and `all`, this has O(2n) time-complexity in the worst case. I wouldn't recommend doing this unless your iterable is known to be very small. …If you're using Python 3, `map` returns an iterable, so it's not an issue.