# What is the equivalent of C++ std::any_of in Python?

Tags: python, c++, lambda

Given `x = [False, False, True]`

How do I evaluate in Python if any of the values of `x` is True without an explicit loop?

Please note that my example above is oversimplified, and the C++ std::any_of function takes a lambda for the unary callback.

If the collection above is an object with a boolean, How do I do acomplish this in Python without having to create a new collection, but just evaluating each element until one of the callback calls return True?

Comment: @JohnDing - I didn't downvote, and don't claim to be able to read minds of downvoters.   But questions that can be easily answered by simply searching through readily available documentation (in this case, of the Python library) tend to attract downvotes, since they demonstrate that the OP has not applied any effort of their own.

Comment: I should probably had asked this to my search engine in terms of the description instead of the name of C++ function. I found https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5217489/check-if-a-predicate-evaluates-true-for-all-elements-in-an-iterable-in-python; but I didn't know collections/containers are called "an iterable" so I just wanted whatever std::any_of is doing in Python.

Answer (score 2):

The `any()` built-in function works like that. So

```py
any(x) is True
```

Check out https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any

Comment: Thank you Jason!

Comment: In the documentation, the build-in any function doesn't have any callback to evaluate each element. Is there any other option?

Comment: I think I found it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1342601/pythonic-way-of-checking-if-a-condition-holds-for-any-element-of-a-list

Comment: `is True` is unecessary, at least per se

Answer (score 2):

Use [`any(iterable)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any):

```
x = [False, False, True]
any(x)  # True.
```